# PrivatePub & Faye-Websocket not working

Tags: ruby, websocket, faye

Just recently my private_pub setup stopped working. I'm not sure why this is because I find it hard to diagnose the problem with the following error:

```
[ERROR] [Faye::RackAdapter] input must be a string or IO
```

Here's a full stacktrace:

```
2012-04-18 13:33:32 [ERROR] [Faye::RackAdapter] input must be a string or IO
Backtrace:
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/lib/yajl.rb:36:in `parse'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/lib/yajl.rb:36:in `parse'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faye-0.8.2/lib/faye/adapters/rack_adapter.rb:98:in `handle_request'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faye-0.8.2/lib/faye/adapters/rack_adapter.rb:91:in `call'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faye-websocket-0.4.5/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:41:in `process'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faye-websocket-0.4.5/lib/faye/adapters/thin.rb:45:in `receive_data'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179:in `run_machine'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4/lib/eventmachine.rb:179:in `run'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on how to debug this problem / fix it?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm searching for the answer everywhere I can, but there are no normal answers. One issue [here](https://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/7ef8a55f15765950) found but not explained good. if it help you I would be happy.

Please, if someone knows why such error happens -- help with this. It is very needed.